# How to create AWS S3 Glacier vault in CDK app by using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, amazon-glacier

Is it possible to create AWS S3 Glacier vault in CDK app by using TypeScript? I don't see TypeScript option in the developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/creating-vaults.html

We can configure [Intelligent Tiering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#intelligent-tiering) for AWS S3 bucket, but I don't think that it's what I am looking for. I found [Creating a S3 Glacier vault](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/glacier-example-creating-a-vault.html) dev guide for JavaScript SDK which describes the process of creating the vault. This is exactly what I need, but I doubt I could use it in CDK TypeScript app.

Anyway. I tried to use `aws-sdk/client-glacier` NPM package. I installed it and created a new instance of the `GlacierClient` class in `cdk.ts` file. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to build the app.

[image]

Here is my `package.json` file.

```
{

  "name": "cdk-app-2",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "bin": {

    "cdk-app-2": "bin/cdk-app-2.js"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "build": "tsc",

    "watch": "tsc -w",

    "test": "jest",

    "cdk": "cdk"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",

    "@types/node": "10.17.27",

    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",

    "aws-cdk": "2.50.0",

    "jest": "^27.5.1",

    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",

    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",

    "typescript": "~3.9.7"

  },

  "dependencies": {

    "@aws-sdk/client-glacier": "^3.204.0",

    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.50.0",

    "constructs": "^10.0.0",

    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"

  }

}
```

Comment: I don’t think it is available. A workaround would be to use a lambda custom resource in your cdk..

Comment: There are two forms of 'Amazon Glacier' -- the original involved Vaults and Archives and the newer one involves S3 storage classes. The original version (with Vaults) was slow and painful to use -- it is best avoided. Plus, using Glacier storage classes in S3 is actually cheaper!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So you proposed to use `StorageClass` instead of S3 Glacier API. Am I right? Does it mean that I can use the example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.StorageClass.html in my CDK app?

Comment: @JosephKatzman Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 Glacier is not supported in either the CDK or [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_S3.html).

As a workaround, add a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) construct.  The Custom Resource's job is to call the SDK APIs to create/update/delete the vault.  It will be invoked during the deployment lifecycle by CloudFormation.  There are several flavours of Custom Resource.  You may be able to use the [custom_resources.AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct, which makes SDK calls easy.  If more control is required, you will need to write your own Lambda in conjunction with a [cdk.CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CustomResource.html).